# IcCube Gantt Chart: How do I properly set up the MDX part for reporting?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

How do I properly set up the MDX for a Gantt Chart, when I want to display a duration (start and end date) for several projects?

Currently, there is no documentation provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a start date, end date and a duration measures:

```
SELECT

  {[Measures].[start date],[Measures].[end date],[Measures].[duration]} ON 0,

  [Project].[Project].[projects].allmembers ON 1

FROM [Gantt]
```